# Make my domains's subfolder link to bluehost wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, dns, bluehost

ex.

My domain is abc.com,

I created a wordpress site on bluehost.

How to set up in both sides to make abc.com/blog link to the wordpress site on bluehost?

abc.com is not/won't be managed by bluehost and can't be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps proxy such as HA Proxy or NGINX could forward the requests back and forth.